# API not accepting my JSON data from Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm new to Python and dealing with JSON.  I'm trying to grab an array of strings from my database and give them to an API.  I don't know why I'm getting the missing data error.   Can you guys take a look?

```
###########################################

rpt_cursor = rpt_conn.cursor()
sql="""SELECT `ContactID` AS 'ContactId' FROM 
`BWG_reports`.`bounce_log_dummy`;"""
rpt_cursor.execute(sql)

row_headers=[x[0] for x in rpt_cursor.description] #this will extract row headers
row_values= rpt_cursor.fetchall()
json_data=[]
for result in row_values:
    json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
results_to_load = json.dumps(json_data)
print(results_to_load) # Prints: [{"ContactId": 9}, {"ContactId": 274556}]


headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

targetlist = '302'
# This is for their PUT to "add multiple contacts to lists".
api_request_url = 'https://api2.xyz.com/api/list/' + str(targetlist) 
+'/contactid/Api_Key/' + bwg_apikey

print(api_request_url) #Prints https://api2.xyz.com/api/list/302/contactid/Api_Key/#####
response = requests.put(api_request_url, headers=headers, data=results_to_load)

print(response) #Prints <Response [200]>
print(response.content) #Prints b'{"status":"error","Message":"ContactId is Required."}'

rpt_conn.commit()
rpt_cursor.close()

###########################################################
```

Edit for Clarity:

I'm passing it this **[{"ContactId": 9}, {"ContactId": 274556}]**
and I'm getting this response body **b'{"status":"error","Message":"ContactId is Required."}'**

The API doc gives this as the from to follow for the request body.
**[
  {
    "ContactId": "string"
  }
]**

When I manually put this data in there test thing I get what I want.
[
  {
    "ContactId": "9"
  },
  {
    "ContactId": "274556"
  }
]

Maybe there is something wrong with json.dumps vs json.load?  Am I not creating a dict, but rather a string that looks like a dict?

EDIT I FIGURED IT OUT!:

This was dumb.

I needed to define **results_to_load = []** as a dict before I loaded it at **results_to_load = json.dumps(json_data)**.

Thanks for all the answers and attempts to help.

Comment: It's essentially impossible to help you if you don't provide a clear description of the error.

Comment: I agree with @LTClipp. This is so hard to read. Are they looking for a list of `ContactId`, or just a single one? You're giving it a list. I would advise you to check with their api.

Comment: @Ywapom His `json_data` is a list of dicts, which seems reasonable. And initializing it to `{}` without replacing that `append` is just going to give an `AttributeError`, and it's not clear what he should replace that `append` with—what's the key for each subdict in your proposed dict?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I have data that looks like this...
[{"ContactId": 9}, {"ContactId": 274556}]

And I'm getting a response that looks like this...
b'{"status":"error","Message":"ContactId is Required."}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go and check the API docs to be specific, but from it seems, the API requires a field with the name `ContactID` which is an array, rather and an array of objects where every object has key as `contactId`

Or

```
//correct
{
    contactId: [9,229]
}
```

instead of

```
// not correct
[{contactId:9}, {contactId:229}]
```

Tweaking this might help:

```
res = {}
contacts = []
for result in row_values:
    contacts.append(result)
res[contactId] = contacts
...
...

response = requests.put(api_request_url, headers=headers, data=res)
```

Comment: This res['ContactId'] = contacts gives me {'ContactId': [(9,), (274556,)]} , but I still just get the ContactId is Required error.

Comment: Check API docs for the expected request body and post it here. That might be helpful

Comment: Expected request body is **[ { "ContactId": "string" } ]**.  I've added that to the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT!:

This was dumb.

I needed to define **results_to_load = []** as an empty dict before I loaded it at **results_to_load = json.dumps(json_data)**.

Thanks for all the answers and attempts to help.